# Login to active directory

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

Hi
I have an active directory that is installed on a machine that belong to different domain than the domain I am doing development on.

And there is no trust relationship between the two domains.

Let's say that domain called "test.com" .

there is an administrator called "test\administrator" with password "admin_password"

When I set up these setting with ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, I will be able to access, and login in to that Active directory and validate users.
I am using these settings

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ADService" connectionString="LDAP://test.com"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

      <authentication mode="Forms"> </authentication>

      <membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
          <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADService" connectionUsername="test\administrator" connectionPassword="admin_password"
               type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
               connectionProtection="None" requiresUniqueEmail="false" enableSearchMethods="true" applicationName="/"/>
        </providers>
      </membership>
</configuration>
```

But when I try to write code from the same web app, or from another app , and try access the active directory from the code, I got error that login failed, unknown user name or password.

and this is my code

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://test.com", "test\administrator", "admin_password", AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind);

            var ds = new DirectorySearcher(de) { Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", "user1@test.com") };
            SearchResultCollection users = ds.FindAll();
```

I tried all types of AuthenticationTypes, and nothing worked
Any idea please

Comment: In the past, I was only able to hunt down those kind of issues by working together with the administrator of the Active Directory server. Usually, he activated event logging and then we saw what was the real cause of the `unknown user name or password` message. I highly recommend that you try something similar, too.

Comment: Try @"test\administrator" or "test\\administrator" instead of "test\administrator".  You are pasing in "\a" character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem
it was very stupid
the domain name should be capital , so the user name should be TEST\administrator

I am surprised that the membership provider was able to deal with this.